# JSON.parse() returns only a part of the object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string in the form:

```
var targetString = 
"{hello: 5, world: 10}, {hello: 4, otherworld: 11}";
```

Using the syntax

```
var targetObject = JSON.parse(targetString)
```

I only receive:

```
targetObject = {
 hello: 5,
 world: 10
}
```

So it only takes the first part and not the second part. How can I prevent this and resolve it?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Property names have to be in double quotes, and you can't have multiple objects unless they're part of an array.

Comment: When I run that code, I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token h`. Your code doesn't do what you say it does *or* what you say it should do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it enclosed in array `[]` and enclose keys within quotes:

```
var targetString = '[{"hello":5,"world":10},{"hello":4,"otherworld":11}]';
var targetObject = JSON.parse(targetString);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct syntax for an array of objects:

```js
var targetString = '[{"hello": 5, "world": 10}, {"hello": 4, "otherworld": 11}]';
var targetArray = JSON.parse(targetString);
console.log(targetArray);
```

The array elements have to be enclosed in square brackets, and the property names have to be in double quotes.

Comment: must they explicitly be **double** quotes? Single quotes will not do? Im really asking btw :)

Comment: Yes, JSON is a very restricted subset of Javascript syntax. Only double quotes are allowed.

Comment: Why do you need a fiddle when you can just click on `Run code snippet` here?

Comment: The fiddle was to test single quotes. Yes, I could have clicked 'copy snippet to answer' and tested it there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the json-keys into double-quotes, otherwise its not valid JSON.

```
var targetString = '[{"hello": 5, "world": 10}, {"hello": 4, "otherworld": 11}]';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `JSON.parse()`'s corresponding method, [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), you'll need to enclose the keys in quotation marks for it to work. While you can generally get away with not using quotes with JavaScript, the official JSON spec does require them.

This, in addition with what Arvind mentioned, should get you what you need.

```
var string = '[{"hello": 5, "world": 10}, {"hello": 4, "otherworld": 11}]';
JSON.parse(string);
// this will return an array with two objects
```